# Want to get the students objects array displayed in the FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, expo

I am trying to make the FlatList component show the data from students objects array. Here's my current code.

```
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import {useState} from 'react';

export default function App() {

  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState(0);
  const [gender, setGender] = useState("");
  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);

  const submit = () => {
    setStudents(students + [
      {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random * 100000),
      name: name,
      age: age,
      gender: gender
      }
    ]);
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Students List</Text>

      <Text style={styles.fieldNames}>Name</Text>
      <TextInput placeholder="Enter name here..." style={styles.inputField} onChangeText={(name) => setName(name)}></TextInput>

      <Text style={styles.fieldNames}>Age</Text>
      <TextInput placeholder="Enter age here..." style={styles.inputField} onChangeText={(age) => setAge(age)}></TextInput>

      <Text style={styles.fieldNames}>Gender</Text>
      <TextInput placeholder="Enter gender here..." style={styles.inputField} onChangeText={(gender) => setGender(gender)}></TextInput>

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttons} onPress={submit}>
        <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Submit</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttons}>
        <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Reset</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <FlatList
        data={students}
        renderItem={({item}) => {
          <Text style={{color: 'black'}}>{item.name}    {item.age}    {item.gender}</Text>
        }}
      />

    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 20,
    fontWeight: 500
  },

  inputField: {
    borderWidth: 2,
    padding: 5,
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginRight: 20
  },

  fieldNames: {
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginTop: 20,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },

  buttons: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 20,
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginRight: 20,
  }

});
```

And here's the screenshot of the app till now. [image]

I have no clue what's going wrong and have failed to find a solution online. Can someone please help? Thank you.

I want the FlatList to display the data from the students objects array.

Answer (score 1):

'+' is a concatenation operator in js. [] + {} will not result in the object getting added as an element to the array.

Try doing this instead:

```
setStudents([...students,
  {
    id: Math.floor(Math.random * 100000),
    name: name,
    age: age,
    gender: gender
  }
]);
```